# PowerShell - SMTP Send

Tags: powershell

So I have a encrypted string stored in a text file that I can call again and again, this is the password for my SMTP Smart Host. This is created via:

```
Read-Host "Enter the Password:" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\EncPW.bin
```

I now need to somehow pass this along with a `$username` to a `-Credential` parameter for a `Send-MailMessage` function. I assume I need to get this into a PSCredential format. But I'm stuck !

```
$password = cat C:\encPW.bin |  ConvertTo-SecureString
$password

$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist      $username,$password
```

As of now I have this, but it $password when I print it outputs `System.Security.SecureString` and I get an error:

```
net_io_connectionclosed
```

When it tries to SMTP send.

Cheers

CALL to SMTP Send:

```
Send-MailMessage -from "TestPS@mydomain.co.uk" -To "someone@mydomain.co.uk" -Subject "Daily Report" -Body "Open Attachment for Report" -smtpServer 85.119.248.54 -Attachments "C:\WSB_Reports\DailyReport.txt" -Credential $cred
```

Comment: securestring can not be printed out(that's the "secure" part). What have you tried? `Send-MailMessage .... -Credential $cred` ? Is this what outputs the error?

Comment: Yeah - then I get: Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Comment: have you tried using a new credential without using Your password-bin file. just to test. `$creds = Get-Credential`

Comment: Can Send-MailMessage use SMTP servers external to the LAN the script runs on? i.e. a Smart Host

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can as long as you don't have some firewall between you and the server blocking port 25.

Comment: And to confirm the -SMTPServer switch how does it take its arguements, IP address, DNS name, within quotes etc?

Comment: An unquoted DNS name works.  BTW are you using Send-MailMessage (the PowerShell built-in) or a third party cmdlet?

Comment: Not sure if it will help but can you show how you're invoking Send-MailMessage.

Comment: is there an Access log available on the smtp-server that logs failed attempts? or have you tried using another smtp server?

Comment: Does it work if you try without the attachment?

Comment: can you send mail using third party software like [blat](http://www.blat.net/) from this workstation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you use Blat tbh - but I can send through telnet when connecting to the send server /

Answer (score 2):

The approach you're taking appears correct assuming your username and password are correct.  Is your username prefixed with the domain e.g. `domain\username`?  I second the suggestion to try the command with a manually supplied credential via `Get-Credential` e.g.:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

If you need to verify the password coming back from the secure string is correct, you can display it like so:

```
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$str =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
$str
```

Comment: I have tried with Get-Credential and have the same error - see my comment on the above post. Thanks :)

Comment: Try this - `telnet mailserver.domain.com 25` and see if you can even reach the machine's SMTP port.

Comment: I can indeed, ehlo and all.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials give you permission to use the mail server?