# Processing a PowerShell SecureString as a parameter or console entry

Tags: powershell, directoryservices, securestring

I'm having a lot of difficulty with a PowerShell script that I'm trying to call a DirectoryServices query from. Currently, if I do a

```
$password = read-host "Password" -asSecureString
```

and subsequently

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$password
```

everything works fine. However if I try to pass the string parameter with a param($password) and then convert it to a secure string with this code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $password
```

After extensive debugging I can see this is working fine in terms of converting the string to a securestring, but I get a bad user/password from DirectoryServices when I use the parameter. Everything works fine when read from the console. Any ideas on what I can do to accept a parameter OR take console input in the absence of a parameter?

This is what I was hoping would work, but doesn't:

```
if($password -eq $null) {
    $password = read-host "Password" -asSecureString
} else {
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $password
}
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$password
```

Comment: huh? You enter password, create securestring, create credentials and extract password? why? the password doesn't change..

Comment: Sorry, that last line you're referring to should be omitted/commented out, it was for debugging purposes.

Comment: After some further debugging, it appears its not even a securestring issue - for some reason directory services won't take the string when it comes from the param, but it does when its prompted. Still unsure whats going on.

Comment: Can you post the directoryservices code that is not working, and the error message you're getting?

Comment: Look at my answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994841/powershell-smtp-send  It shows how to dump the contents of the secure string you get back from `Read-Host -AsSecureString`.  There are some funnies with Read-Host like if you remove the -AsSecureString and type in `!foo<enter>` at the prompt, Read-Host will complain.

Comment: @Keith: Heh, strange indeed, anything that begins with just one exclamation mark (not two)…

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a script and was running into the same issue.  The work around I found in my case was the following:

```
#Prompts for the username/password, enter the username in the form of DomainName\UserName
$Credential = get-credential

#Converts the password to clear text to pass it through correctly as passing through a secure string does not work.
$Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password

#Converts the $Credential to just the DomainName/UsernName.
$Account = $credential.UserName
```

Hopefully this will work in your situation